# Working with large amounts of data in java: speed

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I want to work with 10k-100k data points in the form of 16-tuples (x_1,...,x_16). Most of the elements of the tuple are floats in [0,1], along with one string and some ints.

I want to be able to do lightning fast (preferrably <10ms) math operations on selected points of the data. For example: compute the average of x_15 for all points which satisfy: x_3 is in [0.3,0.4] and x_5 > x_2.

My naive approach would be to do something like create a class for each tuple and then do my math on the classes. For storage i'd just write all the tuples to a text file when the program is finished and load them from there when the program starts.

Is this feasible and will this approach be lightning fast?

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be faster to load the tuples into a 2 dimensional array of floats rather than a 1 dimentional array of class instances, as it appears you would want to be doing a lot of comparison between individual tuples (so you would have to access class properties 100k times+ per query doing it the 1d array way)

Answer (score 2):

If you want fast scanning on a per column basis, I suggest you store each column seperately. e.g. its much faster to scan over a float[] than the same number of objects containing a float. (Your cache would prefer it for a start)

Another approach is to use indexed data but you need to determine if this would be faster for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using a heavily indexed database for a start. Then you can do a lot in database queries so that the only data you actually have to process is the data that matches your criteria. Otherwise speed will come down to things like the sort order of the data n the file, and how much CPU and memory you can throw at it. I suspect that I/O and filtering through the data are likely to be the big time killers.

Answer (score 0):

### Math Speed

If the float values are actualy fixed point values, I believe you will have a speed boost by storing them as integers (or longs) and manipulating them with int arithmetic operations.  For example, you might represent the value 0.000001 as 1 and the value 0.123456 as 123456.

### Memory Footprint

As mentioned in at least one other answer, when you load your values, storing them in an array of values will have a smaller memory footprint than an array of tupple objects (at least 1 less reference per tupple that way).  For example:

```
public class MathTupple
{
    public MathTupple(int tuppleCount)
    {
        valueBlah = new long[tuppleCount];
    }

    private long[] valueBlah;
}
```

Comment: THat's the opposite of what was said in the other answers, isn't it?

Comment: If by the opposite of "e.g. its much faster to scan over a float[] " you mean "not at all the opposite of", then I agree.  Yes.